# Is it correct: $1!+2!+\ldots+n!$ is not divisible by $n+1$ for $n\ge3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factorial

Is it correct: $1!+2!+\ldots+n!$ is not divisible by $n+1$ for $n\ge3$ ?

To me it seems that at least it is true for odd $n$.

**Edit:** The main question, I was dealing with is $1!+2!+\ldots+n!$ is not divisible by any prime $p\le n.$ What I did:

$$1!+2!+\ldots+n!=1!+2!+\ldots+(p-1)!+p!+\ldots+n!$$
So, if I can prove that $1!+2!+\ldots+(p-1)!$ is not divisible by $p,$ it is done.
Taking some random $n,$ I didn't find any counter (my bad choices of $n$) and thought of the above conjecture which is not true as pointed in the below answers.

Comment: Why do you say that it seems true?  Did you do some experiments or do you have other evidence?

Comment: Well, when $n$ is odd, then $n+1$ is even, but this sum is odd.

Comment: The first positive integers $n$, for which the sum is divisible by $n+1$ are : [2, 8, 10, 32, 98]

Comment: This is perfect post without any attempt, that's why people are up-voting ;)

Comment: @Peter but not others up to $9999$ (despite your examples being one less than the apparent pattern $3,9,11,33,99$)

Comment: @Henry Apparently, you have a faster program or used a more clever algorithm :)

Comment: @Peter Did you take every computation modulo $n+1$ or try to compute $n!$ for $n$ large?

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay I have come across many questions that were written much poorer and received many more upvotes. What bothers me more than that is that many answers given to collect reputation points should be rather posted as a comment. (This is a general remark, I do not mean the given answers here)

Comment: @MichaelBurr To be honest, I just used the sum-command, so no wonder it is slow. I have implemented a much better version avoiding to calculate the sum over and over again, which saves already much time.

Comment: Note also that your question is linked to Kurepa's conjecture: see here https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0800

Comment: @Peter, hahaha, atleast we are getting response from people like you (although, comment should not be posted as answer otherwise what is difference b/w math.se and Yahoo answers :) ).

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay You surely understood that I do not mean all answers, so I do not get what you want to say.

Comment: @Kelenner though Kurepa's conjecture looks at divisibility of a sum $1$ more as it includes $0!$

Comment: @Henry Yes, I have said "linked" only...

Comment: No further solution upto $n=10^5$

Comment: And I just arrived at $3\cdot 10^5$ without finding a further solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $m>1$, then $m!$ is even.  Therefore, 
$$
1!+2!+3!+\dots+n!
$$
is odd.  When $n$ is odd, then $n+1$ is even.  Therefore, 
$$
(n+1)\nmid(1!+2!+3!+\dots+n!)
$$
since $2$ divides the LHS, but not the RHS.

On the other hand, when $n=8$,
$$
1!+2!+3!+4!+5!+6!+7!+8!=46233,
$$
which is divisible by $n+1=9$.

Therefore, the claim is true when $n$ is odd, but it is false when $n$ is even.  You may have been detecting that many of the first few odd numbers are prime.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $1!+2!+\cdots+8!=46\,233=9\times5\,137$.

Comment: Thanks for showing great proof sir, appreciate ;)

Comment: Technically speaking, this isn't a *proof*. Rather, it's a hint :))

Comment: It is a counterexample, disproving the claim